# How to get index from a list of nested JSON objects by JSON value - Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

Having this json file:

```
{
"rolesToAdd": [],
"rolesToModify": [
    {
    "name": "administrator",
    "nativeRole": "AdminUser",
    "description": "Administrator role",
    "permissions": [
        {
        "operation": "CanAcceptRequest",
        "name": "Can admin accept request",
        "value": false
        },
        {
        "operation": "CanSeeRequest",
        "name": "Can admin see request",
        "value": false
        }
        ]
    },
    {
    "name": "simpleUser",
    "nativeRole": "User",
    "description": "User role",
    "permissions": [
        {
        "operation": "CanPostRequest",
        "name": "Can user post request",
        "value": false
        },
        {
        "operation": "CanCancel",
        "name": "Can user cancel request",
        "value": false
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I need to change values in this json. I wrote such method to do so:

```
Map configMap = ReadAboveJson()

def setAdminCanSeeRequest(boolean canSee) {
    configMap.rolesToModify[0].permissions[1].value = canSee
}

def setUserCanPostRequest(boolean canPost) {
    configMap.rolesToModify[1].permissions[0].value = canPost
}
```

How to write those methods so they could find the index of element in rolesToModify list by the key "name" being equal to "administrator" and then to be able to find index in permissions list by the key "operation" being equal to "CanSeeRequest"?

I tried to do something like this:

```
 int rolesToModifyIndex = configMap.rolesToModify.findIndexOf { object -> object.name == "administrator"}
```

But it doesn't work. Will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code of `ReadAboveJson` method, maybe there is some issue there, because `findIndexOf` works as you have described:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{
  "rolesToAdd": [],
  "rolesToModify": [
    {
      "name": "administrator",
      "nativeRole": "AdminUser",
      "description": "Administrator role",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "operation": "CanAcceptRequest",
          "name": "Can admin accept request",
          "value": false
        },
        {
          "operation": "CanSeeRequest",
          "name": "Can admin see request",
          "value": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "simpleUser",
      "nativeRole": "User",
      "description": "User role",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "operation": "CanPostRequest",
          "name": "Can user post request",
          "value": false
        },
        {
          "operation": "CanCancel",
          "name": "Can user cancel request",
          "value": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)

assert json.rolesToModify.findIndexOf { it.name == 'simpleUser' } == 1

assert json.rolesToModify.findIndexOf { it.name == 'administrator' } == 0
```

However you can use simpler approach with `find` method that can return a role of a given name, for instance:

```
def user = json.rolesToModify.find { it.name == 'simpleUser' }

assert user.name == 'simpleUser'

assert user.permissions[0].value == false
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the JSON is invalid. Assuming the simple correction, and a setter like so:

```
def setAdminCanSeeRequest = { def configMap, def canSee ->
    myFind(configMap)["value"] = canSee
    configMap
}
```

then the problem can be specified as the following:

```
def configMap = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(s)

assert ! myFind(configMap)["value"]

configMap = setAdminCanSeeRequest(configMap, true)

assert myFind(configMap)["value"]
```

and the implementation of `myFind` is:

```
def myFind = { def configMap ->
    configMap.rolesToModify.find { 
        it['name'] == 'administrator'
    }['permissions'].find {
        it['operation'] = 'CanSeeRequest'
    }
}
```

It is straight-forward to add parameters to `myFind` as desired.